# Why does my Joomla site subdomain copy the main site?

Tags: joomla, backup

I'm not a pro with server management, I mainly do web design on Joomla.

Our IT Manager recently left and I was given access to everything since no-one else in our company knows web.

We have a main site. In this example I'll name the site as cookies.com for example sake.

www.cookies.com is the main site. The domain is cookies.com only. We have 3 server accounts for this.
123reg - to buy the domain and renew
heartinterner - to host the website
1and1 - this is where it is redirected (or something), well all the files are found in virtual servers here.

When I go to the virtual servers, there are a couple of directories, and eventually I can find a folder called "var" which leads me to another directory. I go to "www" and I find so many site folders there, including cookies.com and dev.cookies.com and more

My objective was to backup and restore cookies.com to dev.cookies.com so that I can work on it and replace the original cookies.com later on. I use Akeeba Backup for this.

The issue is, as soon as I started making changes to dev.cookies.com, cookies.com also made those changes.

I'm very confused- what's going on here? Is there something written in the files that direct the database or whatever to the same place, for which reason the changes occur together?

Sorry this is very confusing. Please suggest if you can what I can do. I know this might not be much information.

Thank you!

Comment: After some reesearch, it MIGHT be because the configuration.php has the same information as the original site. What will I need to change in there if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have used the same database for both. Create another database and user for dev.cookies.com and use that database and user to create the new dev site. Check in the configuration.php file that these values should be different.

```
public $db = 'joomla';
public $password = 'db_password';
public $user = 'root';
```

These are all database values. Also check these settings

```
public $log_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla/administrator/logs';
public $tmp_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla/tmp';
```